# R / Shiny promises and futures not working with httr

Tags: r, promise, shiny, httr

I am working in a Shiny app that connects to Comscore using their API. Any attempt at executing POST commands inside future/promises fails with the cryptic error:

```
Warning: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory: Bulk data encryption algorithm failed in selected cipher suite.
```

This happens with any POST attempt, not only when/if I try to call Comscore´s servers. As an example of a simple, harmless and uncomplicated POST request that fails, here is one:

```
rubbish <- future(POST('https://appsilon.com/an-example-of-how-to-use-the-new-r-promises-package/'))
print(value(rubbish))
```

But everything works fine if I don not use futures/promises.

The problem I want to solve is that currently we have an app that works fine in a single user environment, but it must be upgraded for a multiuser scenario to be served by a dedicated Shiny Server machine. The app makes several such calls in a row (from a few dozen to some hundreds), taking from 5 to 15 minutes.

The code is running inside an observeEvent block, triggered by a button clicked by the user when he has configured the request to be submitted.

My actual code is longer, and there are other lines both before and after the POST command in order to prepare the request and then process the received answer.

I have verified that all lines before the POST command get executed, so the problem seems to be there, in the attempt to do a POST connecting to the outside world from inside a promise.

I am using RStudio Server 1.1.453 along with R 3.5.0 in a RHEL server.
Package versions are

- shiny: 1.1.0
- httr: 1.3.1
- future; 1.9.0
- promise: 1.0.1

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Update: I have tried using promises and httr in my local machine (running windows) and the combination httr + promises works fine. So it is a problem with the configuration of RHEL.

Comment: Ok, fixed the ossue after a lot of reading. It was the version of curl that RHEL had installed. It was 7.29, way back to 2013. Updating to latest (7.61).

Comment: I wanted to comment on this as I had a different experience, same error. We are using RHEL, curl 7.29. Our shiny app communicates with S3 via future/promises to load data, and then once more to get the “last updated date”. Removing the “last updated” function resolved the issue. I am unsure why.

Comment: Setting plan(multisession) appears to have resolved this for me on RHEL w/ curl 7.29. I'm not entirely sure why, but I'm guessing it has to do with the difference between multiple R sessions (multisession) and multiple R processes (multicore).